# Is it possible create arrays without declaring the specific size in struct?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Trying to create a `struct` that contains three arrays. I'm unsure of how large to make the arrays until the input is read.

How can i initialize these arrays in the struct if i'm unsure how large they are going to be in the `struct` init? I will know the total amount from the first line of input.

I would be the size that is read in from the use input. Should I just make i a huge number?

```
struct TaskSet
{
    float priority[i];
    float p[i];
    float w[i];
    float d[i];
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use a huge number or use `T *arr` (together with the size):

```
struct TaskSet
{
    float *priority;
    int size_priority;
    ...
    float *d;
    int size_d;
};
```

P.S.: You need to use `malloc` with the size once read from the user.

Comment: The solution here is MUCH better than using a huge number for i for several reasons.  First, you can never be sure that i is "huge enough", and second, nearly all of the time you would be wasting "huge" amounts of space.  Dynamic allocation, as outlined here, is exactly the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've never actually used malloc before. So in my main program, i would have something like Taskset.priority = (int*) malloc (i), where i is the number i'm reading from the file? How would i navigate that? just like an array?

Comment: @user3287789 You should use `Taskset.priority = (float*) malloc (i * sizeof(float))`. And navigate it just like normal arrays.

Comment: thanks again! first time i've ever done that. I'm not sure what you guys get out of this, but this site is incredibly helpful. Really appreciate the input/help.

Comment: @user3287789 This site is fabulous! :P

Answer (score 0):

A struct needs to be a known size at compile-time so that the compiler knows how much space to give each one in memory. Consider the following struct:

```
struct pair{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

When you create a struct as a function variable, the compiler creates enough space for two ints on the stack. If you create an array of five structs (see below) the compiler creates enough space for 2*5=10 contiguous ints on the stack:

```
struct pair p[5];
```

It is not possible for the compiler to create a struct on the stack if it does not know the size of the struct ahead of time.

Pointers are always the same size, so I recommend using a struct of pointers, like in herohuyongtao's sample code.